# How to parse binary data into RapidJson document

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I have a client server setup.
The client serializes JSON documents to binary format.
The client sends the binary data to the server.
The server should convert back the char * buffer to a JSON string.

I did not find a way using 'Document' or other stream API.

example:

The client  is serializing the following data:

```
char * test()
{
    // 1. Parse a JSON string into DOM.
    const char* json = "{\"project\":\"rapidjson\",\"stars\":11}";

    Document d;
    d.Parse(json);

    // 3. Stringify the DOM
    StringBuffer buffer;
    Writer<StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
    d.Accept(writer);

    const char *jsonString = buffer.GetString();
    return jsonString;
}
```

The server code:

```
static const unsigned char JsonBinary[]={0x7b, 0x22, 0x70, 0x72, 0x6f, 0x6a, 0x65, 0x63, 0x74,     0x22, 0x3a, 0x22, 0x72, 0x61, 0x70, 0x69, 0x64, 0x6a, 0x73, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x22, 0x2c, 0x22, 0x73, 0x74, 0x61, 0x72, 0x73, 0x22, 0x3a, 0x31, 0x31, 0x7d};

void deserialize(char * bin)
{
    Document d;
    // how to convert the char * to Document to get back the JSON string?
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Just a little side note - `jsonString` is a pointer to a local `StringBuffer` variable, which gets destroyed on exit from `test()` function, and consequently the returned pointer is no longer valid.

Comment: Another note - the writing method you are using does *not* output binary data, but a text output with the same content as your `json` string.

Comment: Thanks for the notes. I did not find any binary conversion in the library. Perhaps there is no support for that (like BSON format)

Comment: As far as I can understand, no, there is no support for binary formats in RapidJSON - it is just a library to load and save plain text JSONs (your question is a bit confusing in that aspect). As for loading and saving, if you are happy with plain text, can't you just use `<<` and `>>` stream operators?

Comment: @PhilippeRosenfeld did you found a workaround for parsing binary JSON data?